# How can be solved a problem called " 'int' object has no attribute 'getter' "?

Tags: python-3.x, properties, attributes

Ive started learning a python lang. not so long ago. And here is my question.

Is this problem caused by a wrong code or wrong built-in classes?

I tried to make a properties for parametr in a Class. And was given this problem: *'int' object has no attribute 'getter'* =/

Btw, yes, in this code all type of making params are being learned, so it can be a problem, but still i dont understand where is it.

Here a code:

```
from numpy.core.tests.test_mem_overlap import size


class Dog:
    def __init__(self, name="noname", new_size=None):
        if new_size is None:
            new_size = {'height': 0, 'width': 0}
        self.name = name
        self.size = new_size

    # getter. Type 1:
    @property
    def getter_name_property_function(self):
        return self.name

    # props. Type 2:
    @size.getter
    def size(self):
        return self.size

    @size.setter
    def size(self, new_size):
        self.size = new_size

    @size.deleter
    def size(self):
        del self.size

    # props. Type 3:
    def getter_name_property_method(self):
        return self.name

    def setter_name(self, name):
        self.name = name

    def deleter_name(self):
        del self.name

    name = property(getter_name_property_method, setter_name, deleter_name, "properties for name")


if __name__ == '__main__':
    dog = Dog("Sally", {'height': 35, 'width': 80})
    print(dog.size)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is with your declaration of the getter property. Change the code:

```
# props. Type 2:
@size.getter
def size(self):
    return self.size
```

To the following:

```
# props. Type 2:
@property
def size(self):
    return self.size
```